# Azure AD B2C - Custom Policy optionally include a claim in the id_token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a claim that should be optionally included in the id_token sent back to the relying party application. Preferably it would only be included in the id_token when a specific query parameter is sent by the relying party or when a specific scope is requested. The claim is already present in the claims bag during the user journey.

What are the recommended ways to achieve optional claims in Azure AD B2C?

I tried to conditionally set it to null but that still included it with an empty string value when the id_token was created.

Was thinking of trying to emit a whole new claim if certain preconditions are met where I just copy the value of the existing claim to the new claim for certain conditions, and expose the new claim instead of the old one through the UserJourneys output claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with nulling a claim is it doesn't remove it from the claim bag, and the reason it still gets returned with an empty string value.

If I were implementing this I'd do two orchestration steps for sign-in, with a precondition on that parameter existing to determine which to execute. There may be additional steps for achieving this during sign-up.

1. Create a claims transformation to read in your query parameter

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Initialize-Journey">
  <DisplayName>Set-up journey</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="IncludeOptionalClaim" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:includeExtraClaims}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. Call initialize journey

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="initJourney" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Initialize-Journey" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

3. Create Technical Profile with extra claim

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-AdditionalClaims">
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="myAdditionalClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

4. Add preconditions to select correct technical profile

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>IncludeOptionalClaim</Value>
      <Value>true</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>IncludeOptionalClaim</Value>
      <Value>true</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingObjectIdAdditionalClaims" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId-AdditionalClaims" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

This would only read the additional claim(s) and add them to the claims bag the parameter `includeExtraClaims` existed and was set to `true`.

Comment: Had to add `<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>` as metadata, but the general idea helped me out. Thanks!